# How to find the first most frequent, second most frequent, ..., last frequent in text?

Tags: r, text, stringr

I'm trying to find the first most frequent, the second most frequent, ..., the last most frequent words/categories in the following text `cat`.

```
library(stringr)
cat <- c("AA","AA","AA","Ee","Dd","Ee","Bb","Cc","Cc","Cc")
```

OUTPUT that I need:

```
most1 AAA Cc
most2 Ee
most3 Bb Dd
```

Can one help me in this regard? Tnx!

Comment: So something like `split(names(table(cat)), table(cat))`?

Comment: It works in that sense. But how do we know which category is the most frequent, 2nd most frequent....?

Comment: which format? The output of `split` is a list. What format do you want?

Comment: Sort the list before hand. Something like `split(names(sort(table(cat), decreasing = TRUE)), sort(table(cat)))`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `table` like:

```
sort(table(cat), TRUE)
#cat
#AA Cc Ee Bb Dd 
# 3  3  2  1  1
```

And as a character vector:

```
x <- table(cat)
x <- rev(do.call(rbind, lapply(split(names(x), x), paste,collapse = " ")))
cbind(paste0("most", seq(x)), x)
#             x      
#[1,] "most1" "AA Cc"
#[2,] "most2" "Ee"   
#[3,] "most3" "Bb Dd"
```

Variant:

```
x <- table(cat)
x <- do.call(rbind, rev(lapply(split(names(x), x), list)))
as.data.frame(cbind(paste0("most", seq(x)), x))
#     V1     V2
#3 most1 AA, Cc
#2 most2     Ee
#1 most3 Bb, Dd
```

Comment: That's is possible. But I need it in the format I indicated in the output.

Comment: Can I ask you one more thing? I want to consider `most1`, `most2`, `most3` as variable names in my actual data frame. Actually the corresponding value for those variables is `AA Cc`, `Ee`, and `Bb Dd`, respectively. How I can do that?

Comment: Maybe change to `x <- do.call(rbind, rev(lapply(split(names(x), x), list)))`

Comment: It gives me an output which is basically different from the previous result.

Comment: Yes clear. It gives a `list` which holds the variables from `cat` per *most*.

Comment: The corresponding values of `most1` `most2` `most3` is completely changed in my case. Where is my mistake? Would you put your code please?