# How to combine the name of categories having the same frequency in R?

Tags: r, stringr

```
library(stringr)
cat <- c("AA","AA","AA","Ee","Dd","Ee","Bb","Cc","Cc","Cc")
yyy <- table(cat)
# yyy
# AA Bb Cc Dd Ee 
# 3  1  3  1  2
```

For table named `yyy`, the categories `AA` and `Cc` have the same frequency. The same is true for `Bb` and `Dd`. My intention is to give a name like `AA|Cc` for `AA` and `Cc`. By applying the same principle for other categories, how do I name and generate the following table? Thank you!

```
# AA|Cc  Ee  Bb|Dd
#  3      2    1
```

Comment: see your question: [How to find the first most frequent, second most frequent, …](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62024263/10488504)

Comment: @GKi Thank you for your concern. My problem is in connection with what I have in the real data set. Here is it: Once the above table is constructed, I wanna assign `x <- AA|Cc`, `y<-Ee`, and `z<-Bb|Dd`. I will use these `x`, `y`, and `z` for further calculation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
library(dplyr)

cat |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  count(cat) |>
  summarise(value = paste(cat, collapse = "|"), .by = n)

# Output:
  n value
1 3 AA|Cc
2 1 Bb|Dd
3 2    Ee
```